# How to refresh oxyplot plot when data changes

Tags: c#, wpf, graph, oxyplot

[image: GUI for the program]

Oxyplot graphs 13 points which are derived from the 6 user input text boxes. The values in the text boxes are held in public variables in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class. The variables are updated when the user presses enter in the text box. How would I make the refresh button refresh the graph.

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Refresh The Graph
        }
```

I think that this would be done using the

```
PlotModel.RefreshPlot()
```

method, but I am not sure how to implement it because of Oxyplot's poor documentation.

Comment: Sorry for being two years too late, but the best way is not given here. To do this properly, use oxyplot.wpf, DON'T use PlotModel - use Plot, and bind your data to the ItemsSourceProperty - no need to call Invalidate!! It updates as the data updates in real time.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe this is still active. This project was so long ago.

Comment: @AndrewBenjamin It looks like there is no more `Plot` in current version (2022)

Comment: @Jkallus It is still active because you did not accept any answer.

Answer (score 40):

I just updated to a new version of OxyPlot via NuGet.  I'm using OxyPlot.Wpf v20014.1.277.1 and I think you now need to call `InvalidatePlot(bool updateData)` on the `PlotModel` instead of RefreshPlot (which is no longer available).  I tested this in my sample code and it worked as expected.

If you want to refresh the plot *and* update the data collections, you need to pass `true` to the call:

```
PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true)
```

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but would you think using MVVM for a very little project which makes use of some Oxy-plotting makes sense? Or `Plot.Model = ...` and `InvalidatePlot` are good enough?
I realize it's a tricky question, but what's your first thought?

Comment: It's not necessary to pass `true` as an argument, it's the default value of the parameter. Also, I confirm that `RefreshPlot` is no longer available in new releases.

Answer (score 7):

Give `x:Name` to OxyPlot instance in XAML:

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="Plot1"/>
```

and on button click handler, refresh like this:

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Plot1.RefreshPlot(true);
}
```

Comment: Deprecated, not longer available

Answer (score 7):

The cleanest way I've found to get "sort of" auto-update is reacting to CollectionChanged on the collection that is LineSeries' ItemsSource.

In ViewModel:

```
ObservableCollection<DataPoint> Data { get; set; } 
    = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();

public PlotModel PlotModel
{
    get { return _plot_model; }
    set
    {
        _plot_model = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => PlotModel);
    }
}
PlotModel _plot_model;

// Inside constructor:
Data.CollectionChanged += (a, b) => PlotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

Comment: Great answer. This is how binding should be done. In mine I made the ViewModel a BindableObject and called OnPropertyChanged() instead of RaisePropertyChanged().

Comment: @DrCJones the method that raises the `PropertyChanged` event depends on the MVVM library you are using. With MvvmLight, the ViewModels usually inherit from `ViewModelBase`, which has the `RaisePropertyChanged` method. Other libraries might be different.

Comment: Good point @heltonbiker ! I failed to mention I was in a Xamarin project.

Answer (score 6):

In the current OxyPlot.Wpf (1.0.0-unstable1983) you have two options:

1. Bind the `Series.ItemsSource` property from XAML to a collection in your viewmodel and exchange the whole collection, when you need an update. This also allows for concurrent async updates with larger data sets.
2. Bind the `Plot.InvalidateFlag` property of type `int` to your viewmodel and increment whenever you need an update. I haven't tested this approach, though.

The following code illustrates both options (pick one). XAML:

```
<oxy:Plot InvalidateFlag="{Binding InvalidateFlag}">
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataSeries}" />
      </oxy:Plot.Series>
 </oxy:Plot>
```

Updates on the ViewModel:

```
private async Task UpdateAsync()
{
    // TODO do some heavy computation here
    List<DataPoint> data = await ...

    // option 1: Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged on the ItemsSource.
    //           Concurrent access is ok here.
    this.DataSeries = data; // switch data sets

    // option 2: Update the data in place and trigger via flag
    //           Only one update at a time.
    this.DataSeries.Clear();
    data.ForEach(this.DataSeries.Add);
    this.InvalidateFlag++;
}
```

Comment: There is no more `Plot` in current version (2.1.0), right? Or I'm using wrong xmlns?

Answer (score 4):

After having the same question with the same issue, it would seem that the only working solution (at least to my point of view) is as followed :

`PlotView.InvalidatePlot(true)`

Doing so, after updating one or multple `Series` do refresh your `PlotView`.

The refresh rate depends on how often, or at which rate your serie(s) is/are updated.

Here is a code snippet (on Xamarin Android but should work anyway) :

```
PlotView resultsChart = FindViewById<PlotView>(Resource.Id.resultsChart);
PlotModel plotModel = new PlotModel
{
    // set here main properties such as the legend, the title, etc. example :
    Title = "My Awesome Real-Time Updated Chart",
    TitleHorizontalAlignment = TitleHorizontalAlignment.CenteredWithinPlotArea,
    LegendTitle = "I am a Legend",
    LegendOrientation = LegendOrientation.Horizontal,
    LegendPlacement = LegendPlacement.Inside,
    LegendPosition = LegendPosition.TopRight
    // there are many other properties you can set here
}

// now let's define X and Y axis for the plot model

LinearAxis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
xAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
xAxis.Title = "Time (hours)";

LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
yAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
yAxis.Title = "Values";

plotModel.Axes.Add(xAxis);
plotModel.Axes.Add(yAxis);

// Finally let's define a LineSerie

LineSeries lineSerie = new LineSeries
 {
    StrokeThickness = 2,
    CanTrackerInterpolatePoints = false,
    Title =  "Value",
    Smooth = false
  };
plotModel.Series.Add(lineSerie);
resultsChart.Model = plotModel;
```

Now, whenever you need to add `DataPoints` to your `LineSerie` and to updated automatically the `PlotView` accordingly, just do as followed :

```
resultsChart.InvalidatePlot(true);
```

Doing so will automatically refresh your `PlotView`.

On a side note, the `PlotView` will also be updated when an event occurs such as a touch, a pinch to zoom, or any kind of UI-related events.

I hope I could help. I had trouble with this for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

Exists three alternatives how refresh plot (from [OxyPlot documentation](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/common-tasks/refresh-plot.html)):

- Change the `Model` property of the `PlotView` control
- Call `Invalidate` on the `PlotView` control
- Call `Invalidate` on the `PlotModel`

Answer (score 1):

Another two years later... this solution works for me, because I have no oxyplot models and I´m missing some of the named functions from above.

**code behind:**

```
public partial class LineChart : UserControl
{
    public LineChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
        myChart.Title = "hier könnte Ihr Text stehen!";

        this.Points = new List<DataPoint>();
        randomPoints();
    }


    public IList<DataPoint> Points { get; private set; }

    public void randomPoints()
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        String myText = "";

        int anz = rd.Next(30, 60);

        for (int i = 0; i < anz; i++)
            myText += i + "," + rd.Next(0, 99) + ";";

        myText = myText.Substring(0, myText.Length - 1);
        String[] splitText = myText.Split(';');

        for (int i = 0; i < splitText.Length; i++)
        {
            String[] tmp = splitText[i].Split(',');
            Points.Add(new DataPoint(Double.Parse(tmp[0].Trim()), Double.Parse(tmp[1].Trim())));
        }

        while (Points.Count > anz)
            Points.RemoveAt(0);

        myChart.InvalidatePlot(true);
    }
}
```

**To update your data** don't exchange the whole IList, rather add some new DataPoints to it and remove old ones at position 0.

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UxHMI.LineChart"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UxHMI"
         xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="Container" Background="White">
    <oxy:Plot x:Name="myChart" Title="{Binding Title}" FontFamily="Bosch Sans Medium" Foreground="#FF0C6596" FontSize="19" Canvas.Left="298" Canvas.Top="32" Background="AliceBlue" Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries x:Name="ls" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" LineStyle="Solid" Color="ForestGreen" MarkerType="None" MarkerSize="5" MarkerFill="Black">

            </oxy:LineSeries>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Random" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,278,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

important are the **x:Name="myChart"** and **ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"**

I hope this is useful for someone out there